# Picamera record video in one resolution and take stills in three other resolutions

Tags: python, raspicam

I looked into the documentation of the picamera and wondered whether there would be a way to use the splitter option to have the picamera capture a video in 640x480 and asynchronously capture stills in three different resolutions: 1296x972, 640x480 and 2592x1944. So far I am using this command to capture the video.

```
camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (2592, 1944)
camera.framerate = 24
camera.start_recording(output, splitter_port=1, format='yuv', resize=(640,480))
```

I now run a web server with three endpoints in a different thread accessing the same camera object.

```
camera.capture('./hd.png', format='png', use_video_port=True)
camera.capture('./sd.png', format='png', resize=(1296,972), use_video_port=True)
camera.capture('./mb.png', format='png', resize=(640,480), use_video_port=True)
```

However this does not seem to work or rather it takes forever to take a still and sometimes it does not work at all.

Comment: PNG is not hardware accelerated on the Pi and takes ages to encode a full resolution image; use JPEG and things should be *much* faster (the GPU includes hardware acceleration for JPEG and H264 compression)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried capturing in separate scripts? You could write a new script for each resolution you wanted, store the files and have them managed or run via a processing script. Will try and build this myself over the weekend and see if I can add some code to this answer, but the theory should work.